# Why is the fully-symmetric bidirectional case-crossover design biased and the semi-symmetric design not when there are time-trends in the exposure?

Tags: observational-study, case-control-study, environmental-data

I am trying to understand why the fully-symmetric bidirectional case-crossover design is biased when there are time trends in the exposure and why the semi-symmetric design is not biased?

I have tried to read the open access paper by Navidi and Weinhandl: https://t.co/7fSgjBJfN1

Unfortunately I don't really understand their argument because I am not familiar with risk set sampling.

Could someone explain **in conceptual terms** why the fully-symmetric design is biased in the presence of time trends in the exposure?

(Is this issue in any way related to the Monty Hall problem, which is so nicely explained in a few videos by Mike Lawler here: https://mikesmathpage.wordpress.com/2015/08/17/the-monty-hall-problem/ ? Or am I way off base here?)

Thanks for any insights!